# dashStyle property is not working in angular 4

Tags: highcharts

I'm making a chart which has two x-axis and two y-axis on it.
It's a line chart with smooth curve. It should have lines from two series as dash or longdash but when I use dashStyle it throws error.
I have seen many examples where it's working in jsFidler or Plunker.
Below is my code. I'm using Angular 4 with typescript.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpEPO.png)

```
  var ctx = document.getElementById("PumpCurveEvolutionChart") as HTMLElement;

  var chart = Highcharts.chart(ctx, {
    chart:{
      height: 350,
      width: 700,
      marginTop: 30,

    },
    title: {  text: 'Flow (l/S)', verticalAlign: 'bottom'}
    ,
  xAxis: [{
      categories: this.getPumpCurveEvolution.OEMFlow,
  },
  {
    categories: this.getPumpCurveEvolution.CurrentFlow,
    opposite: true,
    labels: { enabled: false },
    minorTickLength: 0,
    tickLength: 0        
  }],
  yAxis:[{
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    labels: { enabled: true},
    title: { text: 'Head (m)'},


  },{
    min: 0,
    max: 110,
    opposite: true,
    labels: { enabled: true},
    title: { text: 'Efficiency (%)'}
  }],
  plotOptions: {
    series: {marker: { enabled: false}, lineWidth: 2},

    //line: { dashStyle: 'dash'}
  },
  legend: {enabled: false,
      layout: 'vertical',
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      x: -30,
      y: 100,
      borderWidth: 0
  },      
  series: [{
    xAxis:0,
    yAxis:0,
    data: this.getPumpCurveEvolution.OEMHead,
  },
  {
    xAxis:0,
    yAxis:1,
    data: this.getPumpCurveEvolution.OEMHydrEfficiency,
  },
  {
    xAxis:1,
    yAxis:0,
    data: this.getPumpCurveEvolution.CurrentHead,
  },
  {
    xAxis:1,
    yAxis:1,
    data: this.getPumpCurveEvolution.CurrentHydrHead,
  }]
});
```

Comment: Please provide a stack trace of the error that you get.

Comment: When I use dashStyle property with individual series as given series: [{
        xAxis:0,
        yAxis:0,
        data: this.getPumpCurveEvolution.OEMHead,
        dashStyle: 'dash',
        
      }]  getting the error 'is not assignable to type 'IndividualSeriesOptions'.
          Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'dashStyle' does not exist in type 'IndividualSeriesOptions' '

Comment: Here's an example of Angular 4 project and `dashStyle` seems to work fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/3jmW5fg4WUajAIc50lYt?p=preview

Comment: @mani hi, how did you resolve? I'm having similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dashStyle by extending HighCharts.IndividualSeriesOptions:

```
export interface IHighChartCustomSeries extends Highcharts.IndividualSeriesOptions {
    dashStyle?: string
}
```